# Как исправить ошибку unexpected T_STRING?

Tags: php

Нужно обработать данные для UnitPay и отправить по ссылке формата:
https:// unitpay.money/pay/PUBLIC-KEY?sum&account&desc&signature

Не получается сгенерировать эту ссылку, ругается на ошибку unexpected T_STRING в строчке:

```
$url = '[URL='https://unitpay.money/pay/.$public_key.?sum=.$sum.&account=.$account.¤cy=.$currency.&desc=.$desc.&signature=.$sign;']https://unitpay.money/pay/'.$public_key.'?sum='.$sum.'&account='.$account.'¤cy='.$currency.'&desc='.$desc.'&signature='.$sign;[/URL]
```

В чем косяк?(

Весь код:

```
<?php

$secretKey = '123';
$publicKey = '123';
$desc = 'Покупка тарифа в Brainarium';
$currency = '643';

$post = (!empty($_POST)) ? true : false;

if($post) {
$name = trim($_POST['name']);
$email = trim($_POST['email']);
$sum = trim($_POST['sum']);

$account = $name." " .$email;

function getFormSignature($account, $currency, $desc, $sum, $secretKey) { 
    $hashStr = $account.'{up}'.$currency.'{up}'.$desc.'{up}'.$sum.'{up}'.$secretKey; return hash('sha256', $hashStr); 
    
} 
$sign = getFormSignature($account, $currency, $desc, $sum, $secret_key); 
$url = '[URL='https://unitpay.money/pay/.$public_key.?sum=.$sum.&account=.$account.¤cy=.$currency.&desc=.$desc.&signature=.$sign;']https://unitpay.money/pay/'.$public_key.'?sum='.$sum.'&account='.$account.'¤cy='.$currency.'&desc='.$desc.'&signature='.$sign;[/URL]

header('Location: '.$url);

} else {
echo 'Не заполнены все поля!';
}
?>
```

Comment: Пора бы кому-то выучить синтаксис PHP для начала.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что в этой строчке после `'[URL=` вы закрываете строку, и затем продолжаете писать текст вне кавычек. Хотя для интерпретатора - это непонятный код, поэтому он и выдаёт ошибку на уровне синтаксиса.

$url = `'[URL=`'https://unitpay.money/pay/.$public_key.?sum=.$sum.&account=.$account.¤cy=.$currency.&desc=.$desc.&signature=.$sign;`']https://unitpay.money/pay/`'.$public_key.`'?sum=`'.$sum.`'&account=`'.$account.`'¤cy=`'.$currency.`'&desc=`'.$desc.`'&signature=`'.$sign;[/URL]

Плюс ко всему, вы в конце этой строки кода:

1. Не поставили `'`, чтобы строку закрыть
2. Не поставили `;`

Полагаю, что вы хотели написать следующее:

```
$url = "[URL='https://unitpay.money/pay/$public_key?sum=$sum&account=$account&cy=$currency&desc=$desc&signature=" . $sign . ";']https://unitpay.money/pay/$public_key?sum=$sum&account=$account&cy=$currency&desc=$desc&signature=" . $sign . ";[/URL]";
```

И, такое чувство, что вы писали текст в обычном текстовом редакторе (да и судя по символу `¤`, ещё и с телефона)

Лучше пишите код с компьютера в том же [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/), или хотя бы скачайте какой-нибудь редактор PHP кода на телефон, чтобы таких очевидных ошибок не допускать и сразу было видно, где Вы не поставили кавычку

Answer (score 0):

[**Конкатенация строк**](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.operators.string.php) в PHP это **точка**, у вас она не стоит, но даже если вы ее добавите это **НЕ** исправит вам ошибку. Какая у вас строка должна быть? Как я понял у вас должно получиться что-то вроде этого:

```
$url = "[URL=https://unitpay.money/pay/$public_key?sum=$sum&account=$account¤cy=$currency&desc=$desc&signature=$sign;']https://unitpay.money/pay/'$public_key'?sum='$sum'&account='$account'¤cy='$currency'&desc='$desc'&signature='$sign;[/URL]";
```